# How to Authenticate API with an XAPP Token using PHP?

Tags: php, api, curl

How do I translate this code into PHP into my script?

```
curl -v -X POST "https://api.artsy.net/api/tokens/xapp_token?client_id=...&client_secret=..."
```

I have both the client_id and client_secret.

Once I have that token, how would I be able to use it to get the information from this example link (https://api.artsy.net:443/api/artworks/4d8b92eb4eb68a1b2c000968)? If I try this url request on [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test, I get this:

```
{
    "type": "auth_error",
    "message": "An application token or a user is required."
}
```

On the [API Docs page](https://developers.artsy.net/docs/http), it does say that the base url is: https://api.artsy.net/api. I'm just not sure how to get the token, and then insert it to be able to get the API data.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could just google 'php curl'.
But anyways, here we go:

```
<?php

$postdata = array();
$postdata['client_id'] = CLIENT_ID;
$postdata['client_secret'] = CLIENT_SECRET;


$cc =  curl_init();
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_POST,1); // set method to POST
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // get the data returned
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.artsy.net/api/tokens/xapp_token");
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
$result = curl_exec($cc);

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick turnaround! I have looked at the php curl documentation, but I'm still struggling with how to isolate the token and then use it to authenticate my request to retrieve the API data...

Comment: @Sam How long until a token expires? If it the token doesnt expire at all, you can just fetch it manually and use it directly without requesting it each time again.

Comment: Token expiration:
"expires_at":"2017-09-01T12:29:40+00:00"